# Change login screen with gksudo -u gdm ... does not work

Tags: 10.10, gdm

I try to change the appearance of the login screen in ubuntu 10.10 with

```
gksudo -u gdm dbus-launch gnome-appearance-properties
```

but it doesn't work. i get the following error.

(gnome-appearance-properties:3624): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
No protocol specified
Anzeige kann nicht geöffnet werden:

What's the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative you can try loading the Gnome appearance properties screen directly at the login window. (This worked for me to change the GDM login background on my computer that is running 10.10.)

Add the gnome-appearance-properties application to the GDM login window autostart list using the following terminal commands:

```
cd /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-appearance-properties.desktop .
```

When you logout, the appearance properties should appear in front of regular GDM login window. Any changes made will be applied to the GDM login window. When you're finished making changes close the appearance properties and log in as usual.

To stop the appearance properties from appearing again, remove the .desktop file from the login window autostart list using these terminal commands:

```
cd /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow
sudo rm gnome-appearance-properties.desktop
```

Comment: is there a solution without login out? and login in?

Answer (score 2):

The method I used a couple days ago in 10.10 was:

1. Log out.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and log in to the virtual console.
3. Run:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0.0
   sudo -u gdm gnome-appearance-properties
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7 or F8</kbd> to switch back to the login screen, where the Appearance Properties window should now be open.
5. Make your changes and then close the Appearance Properties window.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch back to the virtual console and then type `exit` to sign out.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7 or F8</kbd> to get back to the login screen, where you can log in as usual.

Comment: This procedure worked for me except that instead of pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7 to switch to the login screen I needed to press Ctrl+Alt+F8. I don't know the reason for that difference.

Comment: Also tried that but i get the same error message as mentioned above, the other way works.